# An error while passing a new order in magento2

Tags: magento2.2.3, registry

I made a new installation of **Magento 2.2.3**, everything is working just fine.

However, when I do pass an order this error msg shows up:

An error occurred on the server. Please try to place the order again.

when I checked the log, this is the detailed msg:

```
Registry key "sales_order_status_before" already exists {"exception":"[object] (RuntimeException(code: 0): Registry key \"sales_order_status_before\" already exists at public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Registry.php:51)"} []
```

and there's nothing on the internet about it!

Any Help will appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was because of missing items in "sales_order_status_state" table.